# Ninject Wcf Constructor Injection Not Working

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ninject

I am trying to get constructor injection working in a WCF Application but it is calling my parameter-less constructor instead of the one that has [inject] as the parameter.  I installed Ninject WCF via Nuget and it installed the dependencies for me.

Here are my packages:

```
<packages>
    <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
    <package id="Ninject" version="3.0.1.10" targetFramework="net40" />
    <package id="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf" version="3.0.0.5" targetFramework="net40" />
    <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.0.0.7" targetFramework="net40" />
    <package id="WebActivator" version="1.5.1" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

It created a NinjectWebCommon.cs class for me and put it in App_Start.  Below are my kernal bindings from that file.  Note: I am using entity framework pocos and the context is required in order to instantiate a repo.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    var camContext = new STCAMx0Entities();
    var iseaContext = new iseaEntities();

    kernel.Bind<IRepository<EnrgyProfl>>().To<EnrgyProflRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", camContext);
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<GenUnitCost>>().To<GenUnitCostRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", camContext);
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<LglGenUnit>>().To<LglGenUnitRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", camContext);

    kernel.Bind<IRepository<dly_sch>>().To<DlySchRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", iseaContext);
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<DealModel>>().To<WtDealRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", iseaContext);
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<EnrgyProfl>>().To<WtEnergyProfileRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", iseaContext);
}
```

In my service, I have this as my constructor:

```
[Inject]
public CamService(IRepository<dly_sch> dlySchRepo, IRepository<dly_unit> dlyUnitRepo, IRepository<LglGenUnit> lglGenRepo, IRepository<EnrgyProfl> enrgyProflRepo, IRepository<DealModel> wtDealRepo)
{
    _dlySchRepo = dlySchRepo;
    _dlyUnitRepo = dlyUnitRepo;
    _lglGenRepo = lglGenRepo;
    _enrgyProflRepo = enrgyProflRepo;
    _wtDealRepo = wtDealRepo;
}
```

Here is an example of one of my repositories:

```
public class DlySchRepository : IRepository<dly_sch>
{
    private static readonly CommonLogger Log = LogFactory.Singleton.Create(typeof (DlySchRepository));
    private iseaEntities _context = new iseaEntities();
    public DlySchRepository(iseaEntities context) { _context = context; }
    public DlySchRepository() { }
...
```

Please help!!!!

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done all of the steps specified in this article? [How to Use Dependency Injection (Ninject) with WCF Services](http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2011/08/16/dependency-injection-ninject-wcf-service.aspx).  Specifically, steps "Step 3 – Add the “Factory” Attribute to Service1.svc" and "Step 4 – Add Global.asax Make It Inherit from NinjectWcfApplication"